# PHP: count how many times a number appears in an array?

Tags: php, loops

I'm running a loop basically that will make an array that contains a million numbers between 1 and 10, how do I iterate through it and count how many of each there are?

Like:

```
1 - 201491 times  
2 - 23091 times
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a native PHP function for that:

```
$count = array_count_values($array);
print_r($count);
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

Comment: Yep, PHP includes the kitchen sink.

Comment: I agree, get_kitchen_sink() might be in the PHP API also.
But the one above really does work.

Comment: Yep, good work, knew there was a function to do it in one go. Much thanks.